# How to remove annoying message when mounting cifs vers=1.0

Tags: debian, mount, cifs

In debian 11, every n seconds I mount a remote folder shared by an old Windows NT server.

I mount it with the following command:

```python
cmd = "sudo mount -t cifs //%s/%s %s -o user=%s,pass=%s,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,noserverino"%(host, share, path, user, passwd)
os.popen(cmd)
```

It works fine, but in the console at each mount appears this message:

```
CIFS: VFS: Use of the less secure dialect vers=1.0 is not recommended unless required for access to very old server
```

Is there a way, an option to remove this notice?

Comment: This seems like a Python programming question.

Comment: Do you want to simply suppress the notice, or connect using a better method?

Comment: @music2myear I want to simply suppress the notice. But... there are better methods to connect to a Windows NT shared folder?

Comment: One question please. Choose one of your questions and ask it. Do not put more than one question per post.

Comment: @music2myear thank you. I want to suppress the notice.